# MySQL INNER JOIN - how to add extra IF statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, inner-join

I just learned how to use JOINS (so please be gentle ;) ), and wrote this query:

```
SELECT 1
FROM `T1` 
INNER JOIN `T2` ON `T1`.`T1_ID` = `T2`.`REQUIREMENT`
WHERE `T2`.`T1_ID` = XXX
  AND `T1`.`STATEMENT` = YYY
  AND `T2`.`REQUIREMENT` != 0 //last row does not work as intended!
```

It works perfectly without the last condition: if `T1_ID` from `T1` does match `REQUIREMENT` from `T2` for given `T1_ID` (XXX) - it does work. I wanted additional `STATEMENT` from `T1` to be match (YYY) - and it still does work.

But then I realized, that I need to exclude one cause: when `T2`.`REQUIREMENT` is equal to 0, I want this query to return 1 regardless of the JOIN formula. The problem is, that if `T2`.`REQUIREMENT` = 0, I know for sure that there will not be any `T1`.`T1_ID` entry that will match the JOIN requirements. So I understand, that this last condition has no right to work like I'd wish it was.

What I need is some kind of IF statement. Something that would work like:

```
SELECT 1 
    IF (`T2`.`REQUIREMENT`!=0) //if true, don't even go to join, and return 1
       OR (my previous join query)
```

The thing is, that I have no idea how to implement such IF statement into mysql.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Sample data:

T1:

```
id   STATEMENT  T1_ID
1    irrelevant   1
2    irrelevant   5
```

T2:

```
id  T1_ID REQUIREMENT
1    1     0
2    2     0
3    3     1
4    4     3
5    5     4
6    6     5
7    7     6
```

Such setup should return 1 for `T1_ID` equal 1, 2, 3, 6.

In addition, if it's even possible in single query, I'd like it to return 1 as well even if `T1` was empty, for all `T2`.`REQUIREMENT`=0 - in this case `T1_ID` equal 1, 2.

Comment: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: "The thing is, that I have no idea how to implement such IF statement into mysql. Any ideas?" MySQL does not allow conditional SQL parsing and or execution in plain SQL statements..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just FYI, good start on your post and example... tableName.columnName references (or alias.columnName) should always be provided to prevent ambiguity that others don't know your table structure.  Also, you only really need the tick marks for things like reserved words or column names that have spaces (never like these anyhow).

From my reading your question and sample tables T1 and T2... T1 appears to be some Lookup table and has IDs and descriptions associated to said IDs.  Your T2 table appears to be your detail/transaction based table and it may or not have an actual requirement hence your desire to always include those records without a specific requirement.

If this is the case, it sounds like you want "all detail records that have some condition REGARDLESS of a matched requirement ID as found in the lookup table."  If this is accurate, you would be looking for

```
Select
      T2.T1_ID,
      coalesce( T1.Statement, '' ) StatementFromT1Table
   from
      SomeMainTable T2
         LEFT JOIN SomeLookupTable T1
            on T2.T1_ID = T1.T1_ID
   where
         T2.T1_ID = SomeIdParameterValue
      AND (  T1.T1_ID is NULL
         OR  T1.Statement = SomeOtherParameterValue )
```

The join between tables I always try to list the left-side table first, then indent to the right-side table and have my ON condition show the left.column = right.column so you always see the relationship and how table A gets to table B (and nested more as other joins come into play).

The different between (INNER) JOIN and LEFT JOIN is that (INNER) JOIN REQUIRES a record to always match on both tables.   LEFT JOIN means I want everything from the table on the left side REGARDLESS of an actual match in the right table.

So at this point, I get all from T2 alias table first regardless of the answer in T1 alias.  Now, how to deal with the zero remarks id value.  If zero indicates you KNOW there wont be a match in T1, then you can just say I want all records on the T2 side if the T1 side IS NULL... But you also care for a specific statement, hence the OR within the parenthesis test.

The first part of the where is if you were specifically looking for all things of a T1_ID = some value, so that is a primary parameter and only applicable to the T2 side... you are qualifying the T1 side via the AND ( null or other equality test ) condition.

If you have some confidential data, it is ok to randomize / provide sample data, but having real table name reference / context will help us better understand what you are trying to accomplish.  Ambiguity in table names and columns does not help us mentally understand and might have better query solutions having a better understanding.

If I am close and you need additional clarification, please advise and/or edit your original post with additional sample data and final output... such as parameters being filtered for too.

**POST CLARIFICATION.**

Per your comments, here are the clarifications...

The "SomeMainTable T2" is actually a breakdown of the actual table name within your database and "T2" is the ALIAS reference.  Imagine your table name is "SomethingReallyLongDetail".  Would you prefer to write your query something like

```
select
      SomethingReallyLongDetail.Column1,
      SomethingReallyLongDetail.Column7,
      SomethingReallyLongDetail.Column20
   from
      SomethingReallyLongDetail
```

OR...

```
select
      SRL.Column1,
      SRL.Column7,
      SRL.Column20
   from
      SomethingReallyLongDetail SRL
```

In this case, I used an alias "SRL" to more easily correlate to the table name as an acronym / abbreviation vs having to type the long value over and over, then have more chance of typing mistakes.  Simply for readability providing the "alias" reference within the query.  So, I did not know your ACTUAL table name, so I made it up but using the "T1" and "T2" references to stay in-line with your original post.

Next, COALESCE().  Since this query does a LEFT-JOIN,  The right-side table may (or not) actually have a record match on the ID as you know might not always exist.  Since I was trying to pull the "Statement" column from that second table (alias T1), that description could be NULL which you probably would not want to show in any sort of output.  To prevent that, COALESCE() says, give me the value from the first parameter in the list... If that value is null, give me the second value.  In this case the second value is just an empty string.

Parameters in the query.  Your original query had reference to XXX and YYY such as you knew of a specific T1.ID value you wanted to narrow down to pulling out, but a different value YYY as being part of the statement.  So the place where you had an "XXX", I just put a place-holder here for you to apply/put any value you were specifically looking for.  Similarly for your "YYY" value, another place-holder for that.  Just substitute whatever criteria you were looking for.

Finally that AND part of the where clause.  This is for the condition of the LEFT-JOIN.  Since you KNOW that not all records will have a match in the "T1" secondary table, with the LEFT JOIN, the ID will be found and HAVE a value, or there will not be a value and thus NULL.

If there is no matching record, you would never be able to compare some string, int, date, whatever to a column as it would be null.  So I am doing

```
(T1.T1_ID IS NULL  -- as in there was no match
 OR T1.Statement = SomeOtherParameterValue )  -- there WAS a match, and I only want where the statement equals a given value.
```

Per your comments and example results, your query SHOULD be simplified to...

```
Select
      T2.ID,
      T2.T1_ID,
      T2.Requirement,
      coalesce( T1.Statement, '' ) StatementFromT1Table
   from
      T2
         LEFT JOIN T1
            on T2.Requirement = T1.T1_ID
   where
         T2.Requirement = 0
      OR T1.T1_ID IS NOT NULL
```

In your case, the final answer is... I want all records where there is no requirement (thus = 0)  OR the record DOES have a match in the T1 table (thus T1.T1_ID IS NOT NULL)

Comment: I'm so sorry - I'm afraid that Your example seems for me to be too complex to understand... After I implemented it, the querry returns T2.T1_ID - the exact SomeIdParameterValue that I'm giving to it, and alwys empty coalesce column. I guess that I did something wrong - I assumed, that StatementFromT1Table, SomeMainTable and SomeLookupTable are just comments? My data are not confidential, but they are abstract enough that I really have no idea how to present them - the current form is as good as the real data would be.

Comment: Please check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/23Hka6uJ3cX4yhjNA3QchV/0 Afret replacing xxxxxx with values, it does return 1 for t2.t1_id=3, and t2.t1_id=6. It is correct, but for t2.t1_id=1 and t2.t1_id=2 it does not return anything - and I'd like to get 1 as well.

Comment: @Zorann, modified answer for clarification and final answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that you want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT 1
FROM `T2` LEFT JOIN
     `T1`
     ON `T1`.`T1_ID` = `T2`.`REQUIREMENT`
WHERE (`T2`.`REQUIREMENT` <> 0) OR
      (`T1`.`STATEMENT` = YYY AND `T2`.`T1_ID` = XXX);
```

This returns rows for all `T2` values where `REQUIREMENT != 0`.  It also returns the rows generated by the `JOIN`.  Of course `1` is not very descriptive, so you want be able to tell which rows are which.

Your question would be much easier to follow with sample data and desired results.

Comment: the WHERE condition should actually in the ON clause right because it's a LEFT JOIN? i have a feeling MySQL will might handle this LEFT JOIN as a INNER JOIN instead..

Comment: @Gordon I provided sample data - hope that it would help. Your LEFT JOIN option did not solve the problem as I wanted - clarification in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

> if T2.REQUIREMENT=0 I know for sure, that there will not be any
>   T1.T1_ID entry that will match the JOIN requirements

So in order to get 1 returned when `T2.REQUIREMENT=0`, the join must match this condition too:

```
SELECT 1
FROM `T1` INNER JOIN `T2`
ON `T1`.`T1_ID` = `T2`.`REQUIREMENT` OR `T2`.`REQUIREMENT`=0
WHERE `T2`.`T1_ID`=XXX
AND `T1`.`STATEMENT`=YYY
```

**Edit**:
or just append `1`s with UNION for all rows that have `T2.REQUIREMENT=0`:

```
SELECT 1
FROM `T1` INNER JOIN `T2`
ON `T1`.`T1_ID` = `T2`.`REQUIREMENT`
WHERE `T2`.`T1_ID`=XXX
AND `T1`.`STATEMENT`=YYY
UNION ALL
SELECT 1
FROM `T2`
WHERE `T2.REQUIREMENT=0`
```

this will work even if `T1` is empty.

Comment: It does work for every `T1_ID` regardless of state of the T1.

Comment: *It does work for every T1_ID regardless of state of the T1* meaning? The 1st query of the union is your code that joins only when there is a mtach here: ``T1`.`T1_ID` = `T2`.`REQUIREMENT``. the 2nd returns as many 1s as there are rows with `T2.REQUIREMENT=0` in T2

Comment: I checked it for `T1_ID`=500 with empty `T1` and it did return 1, even if it shoud do it for `T1_ID`= 1 or 2 only. This UNION should work like AND, not OR. Is there a way?

Comment: You must add **correct** sample data and **correct** expected result and **explain** clearly,  because all this does not make sense to me. You say that the query on the top of your question returns what you need but you also need 1s for the rows in T2 where `T2.REQUIREMENT=0`. The UNION in my answer does this exactly.

Comment: I'm very sorry - I'm aware, that my english is not perfect and it might cause some missunderstandings. I tought that the two sentences beneth sample table data did clarify it good enough. Please chceck "Such setup should return 1 for T1_ID equal 1, 2, 3, 6." - but Your example does return 1 even for T1_ID=500, so it does not match my expected result.

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oo96GUG6M3ievZLpFAzpMt/0. I removed the WHERE part. Explain why this does not give you what you need.

Comment: The WHERE part is the only part that I wanted to change to get different output. You can remove "AND `T1`.`STATEMENT`=YYY", but not "WHERE `T2`.`T1_ID`=XXX" part. Please check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bC3rVdAnFkmLcwkJHcKpz2/0 What I want is to get 1 only if xxx is 1, 2, 3, or 6.

Comment: This does not run. You must replace XXX with a value.

Comment: I'm aware of this - xxx is the variable that I'm providing to the query - this is the whole point. I repeat: What I want is the query to return 1 only if xxx is equal to 1, 2, 3, or 6 in the given tables state.

Comment: Then replace `T2.T1_ID=XXX` with `T2.T1_ID in (1,2,3,6)` or a an exact value.

Comment: You are aware, that You could do it as well? But here it is: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hzTUZe5tgtzbPe3Hghhx1o/0 I replaced it with 4, so it should NOT return 1... but it does return 1 anyway. This is why I'm claiming that this query does not work as intended.

Comment: It returns 2 rows with 1 for the 2 rows that have `T2.REQUIREMENT=0`. Isn't this what you wanted?

Comment: No. I'm sorry that my clarifications are not clear, but this is not what I want. I want that it would return 1 only for certain t2.t1_id values that I'm providig for the query. To be more specific: I don't care how many 1 I'll receive, this query is just some kind of true/false statement, if it returns anything - true, if nothing - false.

Comment: This is why I said that it does not make sense. Either edit your question and clarify what you want, or post another question with all the relevant data and explanations. The comments section is not the place for this.

Comment: I understand this, but I already edited my question - I think that everything there is clear as it is.